# New MCPE update causes app to crash when loading skin

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have two iPads and two iPhones, and two of the oldest ones of the iPads and one of the iPhones have not had this problem because I think they didn't get this update. The other two, however, are trying to load skins we have created and fail, crashing the game in the process. I could just delete the app and reinstall it but I'm afraid I'll have to pay for it again. How can this be fixed?

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should try looking for it on the [Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MCPE/summary). If you can't find one similar, open one

Answer (score -1):

[no, you won't have to pay agin.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5811807) If you have worlds you want to keep you can copy your worlds folder to your computer and put it back after reinstalling